# Mongodb find with one letter diff

Tags: mongodb

How can I create mongodb query, which returns all documents that matches query but can contain one letter diff

For example if I have these documents

```
{ username: "john", age: 15 },
{ username: "jack", age: 15 },
{ username: "gor", age: 15 },
{ username: "test", age: 15 },
```

And want to make query like this

```
db.user.find({
    username: "johm"
})
```

It should return first document.

Thank you.

Comment: Should the query return document where `username:  'ajohmm'`?

Comment: You are looking for something like the Levenshtein distance to rank the results. Check this probably related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005490/mongodb-sort-results-by-search-term-similarity